# xml to sqlitle loop in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hello all my second question here so be gentle :)

I'm still learning java and android, I'm learning it on my little project but I hit kind of logical wall.

I have XML file

```
<shift_plan>
<plan>
<agent data="John Smith"/>
<date data="6 Jan"/>
<shift data="M-3"/>
</plan>
<plan>
<agent data="John Smith"/>
<date data="7 Jan"/>
<shift data="M-3"/>
</plan>
<plan>
<agent data="John Smith"/>
<date data="8 Jan"/>
<shift data="M-3"/>
</plan>
</shift_plan>
```

on a web and I want to make a loop that would paste each  data  to function that put it to db. I have the function and working db so it looks like updateBD(agent, date, shift ) but how would I go about parsing the xml but to parse the 3 variables than put them in that function and than go again for the next 3 etc...until end of xml

I might be not making much sense I know, this must be something very simple I'm sure but I need really kick in the right direction..

Thanks for any answer,
Vlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports the [XmlPullParser API](http://www.xmlpull.org/) right out of the box. It is an excellent solution for parsing XML documents in Android apps because you can start pulling information from the document right away (it's a streaming XML parser) and its pull-style API is a lot easier to use than that of a push-style streaming XML parser when all you need to do is parse the document into objects.

I am not sure if this is still true in Android 3 and 4, but the Android 2.3.x and earlier implementation of `XmlPullParser` (from the Apache Harmony project) does not support [`getPrefix()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getPrefix%28%29) or [`getAttributePrefix(int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributePrefix%28int%29). Though, this shouldn't affect you because you are not using XML namespaces.

**EDIT:** Examining the git trees corresponding to the platform_frameworks_base tags, it appears that Android 3.2.4 and earlier have the XmlPullParser implementation from the Harmony project whereas beginning with Android 4.0, the implementation switched to [kXML2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I managed to get what I need with DOM XML parser prety much in like this:
  
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); // THIS was what I was missing

//data insert loop
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME); // name child value
String date = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE); // date child value
String shift = parser.getValue(e, KEY_SHIFT); // shift child value

db.createList(name, date, shift);